# Relationship between RRSP and Pension plan in Canada

Tags: canada, pension, rrsp

What is relationship between RRSP and Pension? I know that contribution to Pension Plan reduces your contribution limit to RRSP but is it only certain kind of Pension Plan or all? Does it matter if it is a DC or DB pension considering same contribution amount?